# mqtt not publishing data onto the broker when qos set to 2

Tags: persistence, mqtt, qos

client.publish("topic", payload,qos=2) not publishing data onto the broker whereas the same is working for qos=0 and 1.I have not defined persistence, it is set to default value.

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

from random import *

import time
MQTT_IP='192.168.0.23'
MQTT_PORT=1883
global client
import datetime
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc,qos):

    if rc==0:
        print("MQTT CONNECTION ESTABLISHED")
    print(str(client)+'\n'+str(userdata))
        
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print("Message arrived from "+str(client))
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))

def MQTT_CONNECTION():
    global client
    global MQTT_CLIENT_CONNECTED
    try:
        print("IN mqtt connection")
        client = mqtt.Client()
        client.connect(MQTT_IP,MQTT_PORT)
        client.on_connect = on_connect
        client.on_message = on_message
        MQTT_CLIENT_CONNECTED=True

    except Exception as error:
        print("ERROR IN MQTT CONNECTION",error)
        MQTT_CLIENT_CONNECTED=False
def publish():
    global client
    client.publish("1/MB/EM/3/21/IB",2,qos=2,retain=True)    

if __name__=="__main__":
    MQTT_CONNECTION()
    publish()
```

I have removed all other functionality, for you all to understand better.

Comment: You need to show more of the code so we can see it in context,

Comment: @hardillb I have updated the code for your reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to start the MQTT client network loop. This is to handle the multi step handshake for QOS 2 messaging.

The python Paho client has 3 ways to run the [loop](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paho-mqtt/1.1#network-loop).

1. You can start the loop on a background thread by calling `client.loop_start()`
2. You can start the loop on the current thread, which will then block forever with `client.loop_forever()`
3. You can run the tasks that the loop perform within your own loop by calling `client.loop()` at regular intervals

Which one you choose depends on what else your code is doing, but I suspect that starting the loop on a background thread is probably the best.